# How events in the OS

Tags: windows, events, operating-system

I understand that event is an action or occurrence in the system that caused by hardware device or external program.

But when I'm googling it, I cant find clear explanation about how the system recognizes events and how they look like in the memory (their data structure).

Does someone has simple but good answers for those questions?

Comment: It seems you're looking for an overview of interrupts and [interrupt service routines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) (ISRs).

Comment: Not exactly, interrupts and events have some imagination but they are not the same thing. I saw a comparing table of interrupts vs events but still I did not get the answers I'm looking for..

Comment: You need to describe what you need explained with concrete examples, else people will vote to close your question because it's unclear or too broad.

Comment: As I wrote above, the idea of events is clear. I want to know how an event looks like "behind the scenes". I mean how it looks like in the low-level.

Comment: Maybe if I say I need an explanation about - how event was programmed in the OS?

Comment: You must define what you mean by 'event', since the word is overloaded.  Windows has a low-level synchronization object named 'event', (see MSDN 'CreateEvent').  'event' is also used when discussing GUI message handling. eg 'KeyPress event'.   As others have pointed out, the OS kernel is entered upon interrupts, either syscalls or 'real' hardware interrupts that cause driver code to be run.   Your question is insufficiently specifed and unclear:(

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "event". You said it's an "action or occurrence in the system that caused by hardware device". Well, that's signaled by a hardware interrupt, which is mapped to a handler function (i.e. interrupt service routine). In Windows, the handler might queue a [deferred procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call) (DPC) to handle the non-critical processing of the hardware 'event' at a lower [IRQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRQL_(Windows)).

Answer (score 0):

While there is no standard terminology, in the normal and customary usage events and interrupts are two distinct things. (For this discussion, I am only going to discuss software interrupts in the process context because hardware interrupts are rarely processed as events these days.

Events (as in Windoze and X Windows) are queued. The application processes events by picking them off a queue. Interrupts (as the VMS operating system) are delivered directly  to the application and disrupt the sequential flow of the code.